# Removing disallowed type extension <INPUT is="db-edit">

Tags: dart, webstorm

I previously used `DARTEDITOR`, and an older version of `DART SDK (1.10)`.
I've updated the SDK, and began to use `WebStorm`.
And I got an error:
Removing disallowed type extension `<INPUT is = "db-edit">`

```
class DBEditText extends InputElement  {   String _FieldName = "";

  DBEditText.created() : super.created() {
    //type = "text";
    this.classes.add("editElement");   }

  String DBGetValue() {
    return this.value;   }

  void DBSetValue(String val) {
    this.value = val;   } ....

document.registerElement('db-edit', DBEditText, extendsTag: 'input');

....
```

**HTML**

```
input type='text' id='enum' is='db-edit' size=15
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you add the element to the DOM? Statically in HTML or dynamically by Dart code?

Comment: I add element dynamically.

Comment: I add:
NodeValidator validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowCustomElement('INPUT', attributes: ['is']);
ftab.appendHtml("<input type='text' id='enum' is='db-edit' size=15></input>", validator: validator);

and recive:
Removing disallowed attribute <INPUT class="editElement">
Removing disallowed attribute <INPUT size="15">
Removing disallowed attribute <INPUT id="enum">
Removing disallowed attribute <INPUT type="text">

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, could you please accept it? By clicking the  check-mark below the up/down-vote buttons, to make it obvious your question is answered.

Comment: the problem is not solved

Comment: I see. It's somewhat hard to read code in comments especially when it's not highlighted as code (wrapped with backticks `).     It seems you need to list add all attributes besides `['is', 'class',...]);` Have you tried @AlanKnight s shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.registerElement('db-edit', DBEditText, extendsTag: 'input');
  document.querySelector('button').onClick.listen((e) {
    var inp = document.querySelector('input');
    print(inp.runtimeType);
  });
}

class DBEditText extends InputElement {
  String _FieldName = "";

  DBEditText.created() : super.created() {
    //type = "text";
    this.classes.add("editElement");
  }

  String DBGetValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  void DBSetValue(String val) {
    this.value = val;
  }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <div>input:
      <input type='text' id='enum' is='db-edit' size=15>
    </div>
    <button>click</button>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Clicking the button prints

> DBEditText

**Update**

For the element to be added dynamically you might need a `NodeValidator`

```
  NodeValidator validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowCustomElement('INPUT', attributes: ['is']);
  document.querySelector('body')
      .appendHtml("<input type='text' id='enum' is='db-edit' size=15>", validator: validator);
```

Comment: If you're adding HTML that you trust: that is, you wrote it, it doesn't have user content, and doesn't pose a security risk, then you can tell the validator/sanitizer to just get out of the way and do .appendHtml(..., treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted).   And the thing that changed from the earlier version is that appendHtml now sanitizes/validates, the same way that setInnerHtml always has.

Comment: Thank you. This decision easier